# unable to insert a row in mysql

Tags: mysql, php

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am using LAMP server and a PHP script to connect to an existing Mysql server (local server i.e. host=localhost:3036).

I have created a table called depositor using

```
$sql2="create table depositor(serial int not null auto_increment primary  key, customer_name varchar(50), account_number varchar(20));";
$retval2=mysql_query($sql2, $conn);

if(! $retval2)
{
die('Failed to create the depositor table' .mysql_error());
}
echo "Successfully created the depositor table\n";
```

Now after executing these lines a depositor table was created as per the above schema.

Now, I tried to insert a row into this table using

```
$sql4="insert into depositor (serial_number, customer_name, account_number) values (1,"Hayes","A-102");";
```

this code somehow generates an error and the PHP script is not executed.

The issue is that when I log in to mysql server using command line, I am able to run the same query there(in CLI).

```
insert into depositor (serial_number, customer_name, account_number) values (1,"Hayes","A-102");
```

What am I missing out on?

I even tried

```
insert into depositor (customer_name, account_number) values ("Hayes","A-102");
```

thinking that one of the attribute was auto_increment

The above query executes normally in command line but not when placed in PHP script in the form

```
$sql4="insert into depositor (customer_name, account_number) values ("Hayes","A-102");";
```

Why this discrepancy in the output?

I am also posting the source code.

```
enter code here
<html>
<head>
<title>Challenge01</title></head>
<body>

<?php
$dbhost='localhost:3036';
$dbuser='root';
$dbpass='root';
$conn=mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn)
{
die('Failed to connect to the server</br>' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Connected to the server successfully</br>";

$sql1="create database bank";
$retval1=mysql_query($sql1, $conn);
if(! $retval1)
{
die('Failed to create the database bank</br>' .mysql_error());
}
echo "Database created successfullly</br>";
mysql_select_db('bank');
$sql2="create table depositor(serial int not null auto_increment primary  key, customer_name varchar(50), account_number varchar(20));";

$sql3="create table loan(serial int not null auto_increment primary key, loan_number varchar(10), branch_name varchar(50), amount int);";
$retval2=mysql_query($sql2, $conn);
$retval3=mysql_query($sql3, $conn);
if(! $retval2)
{
die('Failed to create the depositor table</br>' .mysql_error());
}
echo "Successfully created the depositor table</br>";

if(! $retval3)
{
die('Failed to create the loan table</br>' .mysql_error());
}
echo "Successfully created the loan table</br>";
echo "Entering data into the depositor table</br>";


//$sql4 = "insert into depositor ( customer_name, account_number) values ("Hayes","A-102");";

/*
$sql5="insert into depositor (customer_name, account_number) values  ("Johnson","A-101");";
$sql6="insert into depositor values(3,"Johnson","A-201");";
$sql7="insert into depositor values(4,"Jones","A-217");";
$sql8="insert into depositor values(5,"Lindsay","A-222");";
$sql9="insert into depositor values(6,"Smith","A-215");";
$sql10="insert into depositor values(7,"Turner","A-305");";
*/

/*
$retval4=mysql_query($sql4, $conn);
if(! $retval4)
{
die('Could not insert the item in the depositor table' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Data successfully entered\n";*/
/*
$retval5=mysql_query($sql4, $conn);
if(! $retval4)
{
die('Could not insert the item in the depositor table' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Data successfully entered\n";




echo "Now entering data into the loan table\n";
$sql11="insert into loan values(1,"L-11","Round Hill",900);";
$sql12="insert into loan values(2,"L-14","Downtown",1500);";
$sql13="insert into loan values(3,"L-15","Perryridge",1500);";
$sql14="insert into loan values(4,"L-16","Perryridge",1300);";
$sql15="insert into loan values(5,"L-17","Downtown"1000);";
$sql16="insert into loan values(6,"L-23","Redwood",2000);";
$sql17="insert into loan values(7,"L-93","Mianus",500);";

echo "Data successfullly entered\n";
*/


$sqla="select * from depositor;";
$sqlb="select * from loan;";
$retvala=mysql_query($sqla, $conn);
$retvalb=mysql_query($sqlb, $conn);
if(! $retvala)
{
die('Failed to display the depositor table</br>' . mysql_error());
}
echo "The Depositor table is shown above</br>";
if(! $retvalb)
{
die('Failed to display the loan table</br>' . mysql_error());
}
echo "The Loan table is as shown above</br>";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What php function you're using to execute the statement? Can you update the question with the complete script?

Comment: i am using mysql_query($query, $connection) function. here $query  is  a string variable containing the query which needs to be executed and $connection is connection identifier to the local server

Comment: by the way, is there a way to upload the source file instead of posting the screenshots?

Comment: Add the source to the question using copy/paste, inside a code block so that the formatting is correct.

Comment: The image uploaded is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, but the first problem I see is that you created a column called `serial`, then tried to add a value to a column called `serial_number`. The problem with your `$sql4` statement is quoting - you have to escape the internal double quotes or use an escape type function - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php for one recommended way to do this.

Comment: see, there was a mistake from my side (writing serial_number instead of serial), but could you write any query (from among the ones that I have quoted)using escape strings so that I may learn to use them.....From the link that you included, escape strings were used to separate PHP variables from the query portion. this is not the case in my query.....My query (right hand side of assignment operator) does not contain any PHP variable.

Comment: It doesn't have to use a variable, you can pass a constant value to the escape string function.